# How to import variable from another function to other function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to make a simple Simple Interest calculator using Pycharm and tkinter.

There is my code 
It is showing that x is not defined

I already tried to put variable as global.

Also I cant call that function in my finalProgram function because it makes it as endless loop

```
from tkinter import *


def mainWindow():

    label = Label(frame, text = "What do you want to do")
    label.pack()
    but1 = Button(frame, text = "SI", command = SimpleInterest)
    but1.pack()

def SimpleInterest():
    global x
    frame.destroy()
    label5 = Label(frame2,text="Please enter principal amount" )
    label5.pack()
    p = Entry(frame2 )
    p.pack()
    label6 = Label(frame3,text="Please ROI")
    label6.pack()
    r = Entry(frame3, text="Please enter rate of interest")
    r.pack()
    label7 = Label(frame4, text="Please enter time")
    label7.pack()
    t = Entry(frame4, text="Please enter time")
    t.pack()
    buttonmain = Button(frame4, text = "Finlise", command = finalProgram)
    buttonmain.pack()
    global x
    x =(p*r*t)/100
def finalProgram():
    frame2.destroy()
    frame3.destroy()
    frame4.destroy()
    global x
    newlabel = Label(frame5, text = x)


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0,columnspan = 2)
mainWindow()
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row = 0, columnspan =2)
frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row =1, columnspan =2)
frame4 = Frame(root)
frame4.grid(row=2, columnspan =2)
frame5 = Frame(root)
frame5.grid(row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: See [correct](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) implementation of global variable. Declare it outside.

Comment: I am not able to understand clearly can you pls make changes in my program and tell me the final program.       Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simple-gui-calculator-using-tkinter/) is the answer. Please it's for your own benefit try it yourself. If still doesn't work update the question with what changes you made and the error you faced, we'll see how to solve it !

Answer (score 1):

There is only one modification to your code. In the lower section one line is added:

```
x = 0.0
```

This is to ensure you have a variable `x` in global scope. With that variable in global scope you are then able to use (read and write) it within your functions (after you declared it as global with `global x`)

```
from tkinter import *


def mainWindow():

    label = Label(frame, text = "What do you want to do")
    label.pack()
    but1 = Button(frame, text = "SI", command = SimpleInterest)
    but1.pack()

def SimpleInterest():
    global x
    frame.destroy()
    label5 = Label(frame2,text="Please enter principal amount" )
    label5.pack()
    p = Entry(frame2 )
    p.pack()
    label6 = Label(frame3,text="Please ROI")
    label6.pack()
    r = Entry(frame3, text="Please enter rate of interest")
    r.pack()
    label7 = Label(frame4, text="Please enter time")
    label7.pack()
    t = Entry(frame4, text="Please enter time")
    t.pack()
    buttonmain = Button(frame4, text = "Finlise", command = finalProgram)
    buttonmain.pack()
    global x
    x =(p*r*t)/100
def finalProgram():
    frame2.destroy()
    frame3.destroy()
    frame4.destroy()
    global x
    newlabel = Label(frame5, text = x)

x = 0.0
root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0,columnspan = 2)
mainWindow()
frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.grid(row = 0, columnspan =2)
frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.grid(row =1, columnspan =2)
frame4 = Frame(root)
frame4.grid(row=2, columnspan =2)
frame5 = Frame(root)
frame5.grid(row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Please note, that this is only a quick fix for the problem you asked. The general structure of you code is not really good and you should consider learning concepts like classes and/or how you pass arguments into functions.

Comment: Thank you I will surely note that.